# Android : SharedPreferences how to disapear second parameter from activity (if nothing found in sharedPreferences)

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, preferences, shared

So i have this line of code

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
```

I have a label that loads a saved(in shared preferences) name.
When the application starts, if shared preferences find nothing to display it will return the second parameter, which means zero (0).
How do i set this up to show nothing instead of zero?

PS: i tried null or "", but android studio wont let me write it.

Comment: Wy not wrap it in an if statement?

Answer (score 1):

What about returning an empty string as below

```
 String myPref =  sharedPreferences.getString(YOUR_PREFERENCE, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

An `integer`, `boolean`, `float` and every other primitive type cannot be `null`. So, unless the `SharedPreferences` holds an `Object` (e.g. `String`), it cannot be set to null no matter what. If, however, the `SharedPreferences` holds an `Object`, then you can use Java's ternary operator (`?` and `:`) to set the value to null:

```
String myPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, "").equals("") ? null : getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, "");
```

or

```
String myPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, "");
if (myPref.equals(""))
    myPref = null;
```

I don't see why would you need specifically a `null` value, usually, in an `integer`, the `-1` value represents an error. If in your case, every number (including `-1`) should count as a valid input, use a `String` that holds a number when valid (and then parse it to an `integer`) and holds a `null` value when invalid.

Comment: the myPref is not a string.. its SharedPreferences mypref

Comment: and have you tried your first code? it makes no sense at all(no judging)

Comment: @TryMySkills what do you mean? Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: because the second parameter requires integer. and as i said mypref Is not a string as you wrote. Its SharedPreferences object